# Select option styles varies in BB 10 using JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using JQm to build a BB10 app.
I've used two Select options there.
One statically added and the other is added with code.

How ever the code used for the select is identical.

```
<select name="select-choice-2" id="cmbSemester"></select>
```

They vary in styling :

Static Select :

[image: The select added statically with HTML]

Dynamically Added :

[image: Select added with code]

What is causing this ?

Code used is :

```
$cmbSemester = $('<select name="select-choice-2" id="cmbSemester"></select>');
 for(var i = 1; i <= fidx; i++){
      var $option = $("<option value='"+sem_name+"'>"+sem_name+"</option>");
      $cmbSemester.append($option);
 }
 $('#container_two').append($cmbSemester);
```

Comment: are you styling your `select` with any plugin?

Comment: no..I am not using any plugin to style the select